# How can I integrate Google Charts on AMP pages

Tags: charts, amp-html

I use Google Table Charts in my "normal" (NON-AMP) pages. But in the AMP pages they are not there. When I load my page without /AMP at the end I can see the tables and with /AMP at the end not.
Example:
https://lotto-6-aus-49.de/lottozahlen-von-heute-mittwoch-den-20-03-2019
and
https://lotto-6-aus-49.de/lottozahlen-von-heute-mittwoch-den-20-03-2019/amp
To get AMP pages on my site I use a wordpress plugin. I searched for adding "java scripts" in AMP site but cannot find.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need a template with your charts. Let's call that template.html

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
layout="responsive"
frameborder="0"
src="/template.html"></amp-iframe>
```

You can put all of your js into that template. The iFrame should work.
But please keep in mind that iFrames are only allowed when below 80% from the top of the page.

if you need to load dynamic content, you could create a php file which accepts parameters and returns a html file that does include the chart.

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
layout="responsive"
frameborder="0"
src="/charts.php?startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-02-01"></amp-iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't.
You need JavaScript for that which doesn't work with AMP.

added:

iFrame Solution:
First you create a template (html + js) that does show the chart you want to display. Then you import that template file using amp-iframe.

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
layout="responsive"
frameborder="0"
src="pathtotemplate/template.html">
</amp-iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not sure about that. Now I know.

Comment: You could try using an iFrame - and load the charts via iFrame

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me how?